# JavaScript Library - resize, drag, rotate, show handles

Tags: library, javascript, jquery

I am looking for a JavaScript library to manipulate (drag/resize/rotate) objects). I know, there is Jquery UI resize, drag and rotate, but I am looking at a library that combines all together in a very simple way.

A library that allows the following actions on html element(s):

- select, resize, rotate
- display resize and rotate handles
- allow selection of multiple elements allow the same operation(move, resize) on multiple elements

Practically a kind of functionality that PowerPoint allows on elements. I looked around and found some examples, but nothing that provides all out of the box.

I there a library that does all this out of the box?

Some sample images, what I am after, are bellow.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup for [jointjs](https://www.jointjs.com/) which encompasses the requirement you have mentioned. It comes with plugins and has support system as well.

Docs can be found here:

http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.4/index.html

Comment: Looks good, BUT ... "One Rappid license per single developer.
Priced at €1500 each license includes". OP did not ask for a gratis solution, but still... pity, though, as it does look good.